# Can we get the Device object detail / name from a Device handle

Tags: c++, winapi, native

I am writing a DeviceIoControl API hook application which will trace all the DeviceIoControl() calls a target application makes. Following is the signature of DeviceIoControl for easy reference  :

`BOOL WINAPI DeviceIoControl(
  In         HANDLE hDevice,
  In         DWORD dwIoControlCode,
  _In_opt_     LPVOID lpInBuffer,
  In         DWORD nInBufferSize,
  _Out_opt_    LPVOID lpOutBuffer,
  In         DWORD nOutBufferSize,
  _Out_opt_    LPDWORD lpBytesReturned,
  _Inout_opt_  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);`

My problem here is, how do I figure-out which device is this Ioctl being targetted to, i.e. How do I reverse the hDevice HANDLE and find the actual device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NtQueryObject()` to determine the type and name of the object that the handle represents. You might also need to use `QueryDosDevice()` to resolve hardware device names to local filesystem paths.  See this article to get you started:

HOWTO: Enumerate handles

http://forum.sysinternals.com/howto-enumerate-handles_topic18892.html

Once you know the device type, you can 
then use type-specific APIs, like `GetVolumeInformationByHandle()`, `GetFileInformationByHandleEx()`, etc to get more detailed information.